# How to extract specific rows in R?

Tags: r

I would like to extract specific rows from a dataframe into a new dataframe using R. I have two columns: `City` and `Household`. In order to detect move, I want a new dataframe with the households who have not the same city.

For example, if a household appears 3 times with at least one city differents from the others, I keep it. Otherwise, I delete the 3 rows of this household.

```
    City      Household
   Paris              A
   Paris              A
    Nice              A
  Limoge              B
  Limoge              B
Toulouse              C
   Paris              C
```

Here, I want to keep only Household `A` and Household `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dplyr solution : compute the length of unique cities for each household and keep only those with length > 1

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(city=c("Paris","Paris","Nice","Limoge","Limoge","Toulouse","Paris"),
                 household =c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),rep("C",2)))

new_df <- df %>% group_by(household) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(city) > 1)

Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
Groups: household

      city household
1    Paris         A
2    Paris         A
3     Nice         A
4 Toulouse         C
5    Paris         C
```

Edit : added @shadow and @davidarenburg suggestions from the comments

Comment: Or just `df %>% group_by(household) %>% filter(length(unique(city)) > 1)`

Comment: There is `n_distinct` function in `dplyr`

Comment: Thank you! I used: new_df <- df %>% group_by(household) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(city) > 1) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Base R possible solution

```
df1[with(df1, ave(as.character(City), Household, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1L),]
```

Or

```
df1[df1$Household %in% names(which(table(unique(df1)$Household) > 1)),]
```

Or possible `data.table` v >= 1.9.5 [devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) solution

```
library(data.table) # v > 1.9.5, otherwise use length(unique(City))
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(City) > 1L) .SD, by = Household]
```

Or

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[uniqueN(City) > 1L], by = Household]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I used: new_df <- df %>% group_by(household) %>% filter(n_distinct(city) > 1) from the first answer and it worked :)